# Asus netbook: Should CPUID Speed limit should be enabled

Tags: ubuntu-netbook, cpu, bios

I would like to know if it's better to enable the BIOS cpuid speed limit on a netbook or leave it disabled ? Is it setting the optimal cpu speed ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: [This question would be better off on SuperUser](http://superuser.com/questions/ask?title=Asus%20netbook:%20Should%20CPUID%20Speed%20limit%20should%20be%20enabled&tags=netbook%20cpu%20bios%20speed)

Answer (score 1):

Leave it disabled. Unless you really want to try and improve your battery life by minutes. (In my experience, throttling the CPU only gains me 30 minutes, tops. And that's assuming I'm not doing much with it *anyway*)